# Dropdown search query with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble incorporating a dropdown option in my search query. I had the dropdown working fine as radio buttons, but when I tried to change it to a dropdown the query just pulls all of my records. The search bar and checkbox still work fine.

Search page:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php include("../includes/header-home.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col=md-12">
    <p><strong>Search:</strong></p>
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
    <p><input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/></p>
    <p><strong>Type:</strong></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="1"> Medalist</p>

<select name="medal">
<option value="1">Federal Employee of the Year</option>
<option value="2">Career Achievement Medal</option>
<option value="3">Call to Service Medal</option>
<option value="4">Citizen Services Medal</option>
<option value="5">Homeland Security and Law Enforcement Medal</option>
<option value="6">Management Excellence Medal</option>
<option value="7">National Security and International Affairs Medal</option>
<option value="8">Science and Environment Medal</option>
</select>


    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></p>
</form>
    </div></div>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php");?>
```

Search results page:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php
if (!isset ($_POST['search'])) {
    header("Location:admin.php");
}
$search_sqli="SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE 
    (first_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR first_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR city LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR agency LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR subcomponent LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR team_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR achievement LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR profile LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%')" 
. (isset($_POST['type']) && in_array('1', $_POST['type']) ? " AND medalist='1'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['FYE']) && in_array('1', $_POST['FYE']) ? " AND medal='1'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['CAM']) && in_array('2', $_POST['CAM']) ? " AND medal='2'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['C2S']) && in_array('3', $_POST['C2S']) ? " AND medal='3'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['CSM']) && in_array('4', $_POST['CSM']) ? " AND medal='4'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['HSLE']) && in_array('5', $_POST['HSLE']) ? " AND medal='5'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['MEM']) && in_array('6', $_POST['MEM']) ? " AND medal='6'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['NSIA']) && in_array('7', $_POST['NSIA']) ? " AND medal='7'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['SEM']) && in_array('8', $_POST['SEM']) ? " AND medal='8'" : "");


$search_query=mysqli_query($connection, $search_sqli);
if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0)  {
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

?>

<?php include("../includes/header-home.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col=md-12">
     <p>Search:</p>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
    <input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />

    </form>
   <br />
    <p><strong>Search Results:</strong></p>
  <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
     do  {
         ?>
    <p><ul>
    <li><a href="view_profile.php?profile=<?php echo urlencode($search_rs["id"]); ?>"><?php echo $search_rs['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['last_name']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['first_name2']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['last_name2']; ?></a></li></ul></p>     

<?php } while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));

  } else {
      echo "No results found";
  }
  ?>

  <p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="search.php" role="button">Back to search</a></p>
    </div></div>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: You aren't using `$_POST['medal']` anywhere. You are checking on variables that weren't passed through your form (ex. `$_POST['FYE']`, etc.)

Comment: Hm sorry yes I have tried that and it hasn't worked. Would I replace both ie FYE in the search_results page?

Answer (score 0):

Your select has a name of `medal`, so you should be using this in the PHP. For example:

```
. (isset($_POST['medal']) && $_POST['medal'] == '1') ? " AND medal='1'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['medal']) && $_POST['medal'] == '2') ? " AND medal='2'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['medal']) && $_POST['medal'] == '3') ? " AND medal='3'" : "")
... etc
```

There are ways you could simplify this, such as:

```
. (isset($_POST['medal']) && (int)$_POST['medal'] > 0) ? " AND medal='".(int)$_POST['medal']."'" : "")
```

which would replace all 8 lines above.

---

Another note, it looks like your `FYE`, `CAM`, etc. variables were done as an array (ex. `name='FYE[]'`), whereas your `medal` variable is not. Make sure you pay attention to which you are using when you retrieve these in PHP.

Comment: When I replace everything with medal, I now get this error: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in *** on line 24

Comment: Look at the answer again; the `in_array` has been replaced by a `==`. You shouldn't be getting that warning with the code above.